# Lotus notes survey form

Tags: lotus

I have Created a Notes Survey form using Lotus Notes Designer.

I select "Preview in Notes" and from there i forward the survey form to end user.

However this goes as an email and End user's has to Click on reply button to select their answers and then reply.

I am looking for some Notes Script / Commands which i can embed in a Notes button on the form, which will help end user to select the answer and once done, the reply should automatically mailed back to us.

Please let me know if additional information required, related to requirement.

**Note**: I am new to Notes Designer, and unable to club multiple options to get this working.

Answer (score 2):

This is NOT the sense of a Lotus Notes application to send the information via mail. The most you do is, to send a button with the Command `@Command([Compose]; "YourServer" : "YourDatabase.nsf"; "YourForm")`

To the users. When they click the button, a new document with your form is created. Then you use `@Command([FileSave])` in an action to save the document. Usually one checks, using @dblookup, if there is already an entry fo that user an prohibits more than one document per user.

Then you create views to show the documents and see instantly:
How many users took part so far,
How many users selected option 1, option 2, etc.

You have all the information in one place, it is structured and can be easily read / found / evaluated.
Sending mails around would meen, that you have to collect that information yourself and count manually...

Comment: I assume Venu modified the mail database. It is indeed far better to create a new application, add the Survey form, add some views and agents if need be. The final step is to send a mail to all users with a link to the Survey application.

Comment: @Torsten: Yes i completely agree with your post, that sending forms in the form of mail is not the best option to use. But i am unable to get a DB created which can be used for this option. So i am trying to check if there is any best option to get the survey done through email's and get the response back.

Comment: @D.Bugger: Yes i have done just the first option, creating a form by creating new application in Lotus Notes Designer. However am not much familiar with other options like, View and Agents which can be incorporated with this form to make more sense out of it. :-(